# Bootstrap disabled buttons not staying

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is once a button is clicked, disable it, then run a function, then once its done running the function, re enable the button, I am trying this, but the button only disables for a second, and then re-enables, before the function is done running:

```
<button onclick='this.disabled=true;stop($vpsid)' type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Stop</button>
```

Stop function:

```
function stop(vpsid){
   $.post('functions.php', {"func":"shutdown", "vpsid":vpsid}, function(data) {
 alert(data);});
}
```

Comment: show us your `stop()` function, also take a look at the "loading state" example in [Bootstrap's docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons), it may be useful for you

Comment: is stop asynchronous?

Comment: and where are you re-enabling the button? if you're using asynchronous functions (AJAX) you need to use a callback otherwise the code won't "wait" for the call to finish

Comment: @koala_dev Would my current callback be alert(data)? How would I go about reenabling the button in here, I do not know the ID of the button or name because buttons are just echoed with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX calls are asynchronous so you need to use a callback function. I suggest you use jQuery to attach the click handler and use Bootstrap's loading state for buttons:

**HTML**

```
<button data-vpsid='$vpsid' type='button' data-loading-text='Stopping...' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-stop'>Stop</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.btn-stop').click(function () {
    $(this).button('loading');
    $.ajax('functions.php', {
        data: {
            "func": "shutdown",
            "vpsid": $(this).data('vpsid')
        },
        type: 'post',
        complete: function () {
            $(this).button('reset');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not seem to be working. The buttons do not do anything when pressed.

Comment: Here is one of the buttons: `<button data-loading-text="Stopping..." data-vpsid="121" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-stop">Stop</button>`

Comment: @user2484067 have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: Yep, nothing. Here is a link to the page: http://dev.cj.gy/cj/vz.php I have turned off the Ajax refreshing of the table so you can inspect element.

Comment: @user2484067 you're running jQuery code before the page has finished loading, wrap your code inside a document ready handler: `$(document).ready(function(...));`

Comment: @user2484067 yes, also if the three types of button perform similar tasks it would be worth looking into having only one handler and adjusting the `func` parameter according to the type of button clicked

Comment: I have tried wrapping each individual function in the document ready, and I have tried wrapping everything, same result.